# Check radio-buttons - complex logic

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a long list of questions (~100) and 4 radio-buttons for each with the same values (*Yes, No, A/A, N/A*). Some are **disabled** (applied .disabled class) and ***among them*** there are already default values set, some don't, - and that's my target set - I want to check a radio-button with value 'No' for each question with .disabled class that doesn't have default value selected yet.

I've tried a different methods and can't figure out how to make it working the way I want:

```
// selects all with no values, but I can't get to the child elements
$('.disabled').filter(':not(:checked)')
```

and second

```
// get all children with value 'No', but also overwrites already selected values
$('.disabled').find(':radio[value="No"]')
```

Please help!

Comment: Try $('radio.disabled[value="No"]').not(':checked'); If this doesn't work, please provide an HTML example or fiddle.

Comment: Please provide sample markup (HTML). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your logic correctly, this should do it:

***I want to check a radio-button with value 'No' for each question with .disabled class that doesn't have default value selected yet.***

```
$(':radio.disabled[value=No]').each(function() {
    $(':radio[name="' + this.name + '"]:checked').length > 0 ||  
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/x7rqpL54/1/)

Comment: He mentioned he wanted the ones with no default values. Your code would change the ones with the default values.

Comment: To clarify, If question 1 is disabled with the answer of "Yes" and question 2 is disabled with no answers, you would get the inputs with the value of "No" from both questions. He only wants the ones with no answers yet.

Comment: Please follow the full logic; the `.length > 0` takes care of that.  Let me borrow @ArunPJohny's markup for a demo just to verify.

Comment: I see it now. I didn't realize that was a boolean statement on line 2. This should work.

Comment: Cool! I know writing that statement in two lines would cause confusion.

Comment: `$(':radio:disabled[value="No"]').each(function() {
   $(':radio[name="' + this.name + '"]:checked').length > 0 ||
   $(this).prop('checked',true);
});`

worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Great!! Glad it worked. Was not sure if you were using a `.disabled` class or the `disabled` attribute. Now it's clear. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Well, I have .disabled class applied, and was disabling actual fields after the values settings (this code), because I thought it wouldn't allow me to set the value on the disabled radio-buttons.
But I had to put the code where I disable the fields prior the code you provided, as :disabled didn't work.
I was using `$('.disabled.) selection and it worked, but I don't know how to combine it with `:radio` - `$(':radio.disabled')` didn't work for me.